# How to align all widgets in same line using html or css?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

The code at the bottom works as desired except for widget alignment, as illustrated below. Any recommendations for how to align all widgets together in-line (except for the necessary wrapping which is working fine in the code) as illustrated and described below? In the illustration, the red describes what I'd like to change, and the black are just some casual observations.

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"), 
  rHandsontableOutput("hottable1"),       
  tags$div(id = "placeholder")            
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTbl1 <- reactiveValues(base = data1)  

  observeEvent(input$hottable1,{uiTbl1$base <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)})
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTbl1$base, rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- gsub("\\.", "", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%OS3"))
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "DT")
    uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]] <- data1 
    
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = divID,
        style = "display:inline-block;
                 margin-right: 10px;
                 margin-top: 10px;
                 vertical-align: top;",
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID),
        hr()
      )
    )
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]], rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Put the first table in the `#placeholder` div.

Comment: In the `UI` section, I moved the table into the first tags like this `tags$div(id="placeholder",rHandsontableOutput("hottable1"))` and I still get the same illustrated output.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Do `tags$div(id = "placeholder, tags$div(style = "display: inline-block;", rHandsontableOutput("hottable1")))`.

Comment: OK yes that works very nicely, thank you! For any R newbies out there, don't forget the quote marks around the placeholder, like this: `tags$div(id = "placeholder",...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflecting S. Laurent's solution in the comments, below is complete code including alignment parameters for super-clean output of multiple dynamic tables:

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"), 
  tags$div(id = "placeholder", 
    tags$div(
      style = "display: inline-block;
               margin-right: 6px;
               margin-top: 10px;
               vertical-align: top;", 
      rHandsontableOutput("hottable1")
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTbl1 <- reactiveValues(base = data1)  

  observeEvent(input$hottable1,{uiTbl1$base <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)})
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTbl1$base,rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- gsub("\\.", "", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%OS3"))
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "DT")
    uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]] <- data1 
    
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = divID,
        style = "display:inline-block;
                 margin-right: 10px;
                 margin-top: 10px;
                 vertical-align: top;",
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID)
      )
    )
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]],rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Illustration of the addition of 10 dynamic tables:

[image]